# GSView and Ghostscript setup for postscript

Tags: adobe, postscript, adobe-illustrator

Can't find a way to set up GSview and Ghostscript for using Postscript. Saw that the newest version of Ghostscript isn't working with GSview anymore. And link to their download page https://ghostscript.com/releases/index.html/gsdnld.html isn't working.
The problem is when I try to open a .ps file in GS view: "can't load Ghostscript DLL"
Also, can I use VScode to write postscript or is there something specified for this?

Comment: The URL should be https://www.ghostscript.com/releases/gsdnld.html where did you get the one you are using ? If it's in the documentation that needs fixed. But as you stated, GSView won't work with the current version of Ghostscript, you would need a considerably older version of Ghostscript (some older versions are still available for download). That said, Ghostscript itself will render PostScript to the display device on most OS's if that's all you want. You can write PostScript programs with any text editor, or simply type at the Ghostscript interactive prompt.

Comment: Got it from my profesor's instructions on how to set it up

Comment: Ah, well I'm afraid your professor's instructions have an error, or perhaps more charitably, are out of date :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, need Ghostscript version 9.52

Also, in the bin folder of Ghostscript you will find a .dll file that you'll need to paste directly in the GSView folder.

Comment: There is no version 9.5.2 of Ghostscript. Possibly you mean 9.52 ? That will only work with PostScript, not PDF. Also you do not need to copy the DLL, the Options->Easy Configure should be able to find all the installed versions of Ghostscript and offer them to you. Failing that Options->Advanced configure will offer you a dialog where you can type the location of the DLL file.

Comment: Yeah, that one, but you can't find it on the official site anymore, you can find it on Github. Didn't try your way, but mine works just fine, and it worked for my colleagues.